# Spring boot SQS listener makes message visible if error/exception in processing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, sqslistener

As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) , The visibility timeout begins when Amazon SQS returns a message. During this time, the consumer processes and deletes the message. However, if the consumer fails before deleting the message and your system doesn't call the DeleteMessage action for that message before the visibility timeout expires, the message becomes visible.

While using spring boot 3 `@SqsListener`, the default acknowledgement mode is ON_SUCCESS as [documentation](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-RC2/reference/html/index.html#sqscontaineroptions-descriptions).

Now if the acknowledgement mode is `ON_SUCCESS` and visibility timeout is 30 minutes but the processing of message fails at 15 minutes. Will the message be immediately visible after failure or SQS will wait 30 minutes to make messages visible to other consumers.